# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed, setup.py not found

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, setup.py

i started to learn python, i using pycharm, mac, and i'm trying to import mate expansion package.. i add this line at the head of my python file: `"from mate import *"` and it doesn't work, i try to install the `mate` package and every time i do it i get this error, 
i also put this line in terminal `"python setup.py install"` but `setup.py` isn't found...
need some help, thanks :)

```
Collecting mate
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/fd/1089e5b33e0590f6201c3c9b50014dabf9ccaeb2e2546c29cc4abf06e425/mate-0.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/vcversioner/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'vcversioner' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for vcversioner>=2.16.0.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/m3/2d4zt3717c11xbz6fr5ghfkr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/mate/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        classifiers=classifiers,
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 142, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 137, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 586, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1075, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 653, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Users/Daniel/Developer/Python/PythonFundamentals/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('vcversioner>=2.16.0.0')

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m3/2d4zt3717c11xbz6fr5ghfkr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/mate/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the dependency using [pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

`mate` is on PyPi repositories ([link](https://pypi.org/project/mate/)), so you can install it using `pip install mate`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my case, appear to be
that I was needed to download a package call "vcversioner" that was missed. 
https://pypi.org/project/vcversioner/ 
without this package i could'nt download new packages to pycharm
i used this commend line to download vcversioner -> pip install vcversioner 
and it solved the problem